# Adding Minutes to Date is not changing the Date C# .NET

Tags: c#, datetime

double TotalMinute=300.0
double TotalMinutesAdded=1378.0

```
double TotalMinute=300.0
double TotalMinutesAdded=1378.0

foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {

                    //Add The above Timings to each Row's 2nd Column
                    DateTime correctDate=Convert.ToDateTime(dr[2]);

                    correctDate.AddMinutes(TotalMinute);
                    correctDate.AddMinutes(TotalMinutesAdded);

                    dr[2]=correctDate;

                }
```

Comment: The MSDN library needs to have at one example for every MSDN method entry so people get it right away.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addminutes%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned, due to `DateTime` objects being immutable you have to reassign the variable.

However, a point to note is that you can chain the manipulations as so:

```
correctDate = correctDate.AddMinutes(TotalMinute)
                         .AddMinutes(TotalMinutesAdded);
```

Answer (score 17):

DateTiem Add* functions are not supposed to change current DateTime value. They RETURN the new Value.

If you want your value changed, type like this:

```
correctDate = correctDate.AddMinutes(TotalMinute);
```

Comment: Given that `correctDate` is a `DateTime`, I'm not sure what the `.Value` is doing - but your point is clear enough ;-p

Answer (score 6):

DateTime is immutable; functions like AddMinutes return a **new** DateTime; so you need to catch the returned value:

```
DateTime foo = ...
DateTime bar = foo.AddMinutes(5);
```

Comment: It would be really nice if the only instance member in DateTime were marked readonly since it is in fact immutable.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the correctDate variable to instance returned from the AddMinutes call:

```
correctDate = correctDate.AddMinutes(TotalMinute);
```

Answer (score 1):

DateTime is an immutable type, much like String is. You would write date = date.AddDays(1) like you would write str = str.Replace("hello", "").

Answer (score 0):

AddMinutes() does not change the value of the original DateTime. It returns a new DateTime with the new value that you have to assign to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with

```
correctDate.AddMinutes(TotalMinute); 
correctDate.AddMinutes(TotalMinutesAdded);
```

it should be

```
correctDate = correctDate.AddMinutes(TotalMinute); 
correctDate = correctDate.AddMinutes(TotalMinutesAdded);
```

The AddMinutes method returns the result, not adding the minutes to correctDate

Answer (score 0):

...and to add say 5 minutes to the current time to a datetime variable:

```
dim dateFive_Minute_Time as datetime

dateFive_Minute_Time = Now.AddMinutes(5)
```